# selected index of DDL is always equal to Zero in asp .net

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, drop-down-menu, selectedindexchanged

I have a Program Class, with properties as Id, ProgramName,ShortName and Code, im my app
I have a ASP DDL like

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DDLProgram" runat="server" 
            OnSelectedIndexChanged ="OnDDLProgramChanged" AutoPostBack = "true">
    </asp:DropDownList>
```

My OnDDLProgramChanged method is defined as

```
protected void OnDDLProgramChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            List<CcProgramEntity> programEntities = GetAllPrograms();

            DDLProgram.DataSource = programEntities;
            DDLProgram.DataTextField = "Shortname";
            DDLProgram.DataValueField = "Id";

            //My Problem goes here
            string programCode = programEntities[DDLProgram.SelectedIndex].Code;
        }
```

My list is getting all the records correctly, I have checked it. But whenever I am changing an item in the DDL, the selected index in not changing. The selected index is remaining zero.Therefore, I am not being able to get the code of other items but the 0 index's item.

Can anyone help me in this case?

Comment: Do you have `IsPostBack` check in your page_load ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are binding the data again in your `selectedIndex Change event` and it will reset your current SelectedIndex after rebinding. You don't need to rebind the data to your dropdown in `SelectedIndex Change Event`

It should be like..

```
protected void OnDDLProgramChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string programCode = programEntities[DDLProgram.SelectedIndex].Code;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your kind suggesion, I have modified my code, Now it is looking much neater and cleaner

Answer (score 3):

You have to bind data to the DropDownList on page load method

```
if (!IsPostBack)
{
    DDLProgram.DataSource = programEntities;
    DDLProgram.DataTextField = "Shortname";
    DDLProgram.DataValueField = "Id";
    DDLProgram.DataBind();
}
```

Otherwise it will bind data everytime and hence clear the selection

Comment: @Eranga: Thanx for the Solution, it worked perfectly for me. But now its Happening only when I am Changing the Item. What If I Want to make it work for the first time the page is loaded? I have More tha n one DDL in my page and I am binding all of them by a method Bind DDLs(). I am calling this M<ethod inside the if(!IsPostBack) condition of pageload method

Comment: @Pankouri What do you mean by `its Happening only when I am Changing the Item`? are you the drop down list in `OnDDLProgramChanged`?

Answer (score 1):

Why are you assigning the DataSource in `OnDDLProgramChanged`, this would be resetting the selection you make.